# How to achieve asynchronous computing?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous

I have been thinking of different approaches to achieve asynchronous processing in Java. I thought of a few possibilities and wanted to get your opinion on whether some of them are better than other, and maybe get further suggestions on how this can be done. The most common use-case that comes to mind is sending packets of data over a connection (e.g. TCP) with the following API `void sendData(Data data)` or even `void sendData(Data data, Handler handler)`. Here are a few ideas I had:

1. Dedicated Data sending loop - have a didicated thread, that behaves a bit like Event Dispatch Thread in Java, that all other threads call and submit a request. These requests are stored in a queue and periodically that queu is drained and all requests are sent.
2. Use background thread to drain the queue - the Connection could maintain the list of pending requests, and have a background thread to drain the queue (with some synchronization)
3. Executor service - pass the request to the service and call the Handler from the background thread.
4. Asynchronous channel - most high-level approach, delegate over to the implementation

Is any of those better to use, or if you have  any other general ideas in mind, please share your comments.

Comment: [`FutureTask`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html): "A cancellable asynchronous computation."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of your suggestions are actually different ways of dressing up the same thing.

Behind the scenes the executor service has a pool of 1 or more background threads draining a queue. Requests are submitted to it.

1 and 2 are both ways of saying "queue up stuff to do, have a thread that processes it"

So basically 1 and 2 are both variants of each other. They are also a subset of 3.

For 4. I'm not sure what you mean here?

An `ExecutorService` is designed to do exactly what you are trying to do - if you have more than one thread to execute the tasks then it's clearly the way to do it.

If you only have a single thread you could still use an `ExecutorService` but the choice is less clear. It would be reasonably simple just to use a thread and a `BlockingQueue` so that might be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I would always use an executor service to do concurrency. They are high level enough to hide the complexity of managing threads and allow thread reuse. You could either submit tasks to the executor, which will effectively act as a queue, or have many tasks running that use a synchronized queue (like a blocking queue) to share data. The latter might allow more flexibility, e.g., batching of queue items.

I also highly recommend the Guava [`ListenableFuture`](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained) as it might solve a lot of problems you might run into when working with concurrency.

Answer (score 0):

You should clearly design your asynchronous pipeline as a graph with data/event dependencies. Typical graph consists of two kinds of nodes:

```
fast handler:
     immediately invoked when an event happens and:
     probably stores the event,
     and/or calls another fast handler,
     and/or submits an asynchronous task to an executor

task:
     runs and issues events (that is, calls fast handlers)
```

So basically you need to develop two independent layers: fast handlers and task executors. Executors are universal and can be taken from java.util.concurrent package. Fast handlers greatly depend on your problem domain and there is no universal library for all cases. For example, a pure queue is a fast handler which only stores events, and so is almost useless.

If you work with I/O, you need to employ standard I/O libraries so that that they issue I/O events for your handlers. It can be build using threads for synchronous I/O, or with Selector threads or Asynchronous channels for async I/O.

Fast handler example used with NIO2 Asynchronous channels:

```
 class ConnectionAcceptor  implements CompletionHandler<AsynchronousSocketChannel, Void>{
   AsynchronousServerSocketChannel assc;
   int maxConn;// max number of simultaneous connections
   int connCount=0;

   /* called on creation to start listening incoming client connection requests */
   void allowAccept() {
       assc.accept(null, this);
   }

   /* called by I/O layer when a client connection requested */
   public synchronized void completed(AsynchronousSocketChannel result, Void attachment) {
      executor.exec(new Connection(result));
      connCount++;
      if (connCount<maxConn) {
        allowAccept();
      }
   }

   /* called by Connection when it is closed */
   synchronized void connClosed() {
      if (connCount==maxConn) {
        allowAccept();
      }
      connCount--;
   }
}
```

This handler has 3 entry points and handles 3 kinds of events. Similary, handler to make reading or writing (but not both) can be created. Instead of connCount, its internal state contains a boolean flag indicating that an I/O operation is in progress, and a queue for buffers waiting for AsynchronousSocketChannel to end started operation.